# Awk for i in range NF, if $i ~ /pattern/ print $i

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to find a field in a line containing n fields. The number of fields is variable and the position of my target field is not always the same (i.e. it is not always something like $4). I am trying to come up with a short code to the effect of "For a field $i in range 1 to NF, if $i contains /pattern/ print $i" such as the following, which doesn't work:

```
awk'{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)} if ($i~/Start/) {print $i}' <filename>
```

I am trying to print a whole column if the column has the label I am attempting to pattern match. For example, if the column is /Alt/, I would like to print that whole column. But if I don't know the field in advance, how can I find that field number and then use it to print the field? Here is a sample of the table (genomics data):

```
Chr Start End Ref Alt Func.refGene Gene.refGene
1 865584 865584 G A exonic SAMD11
1 865628 865628 G A exonic SAMD11
1 865662 865662 G A exonic SAMD11
1 865694 865694 C T exonic SAMD11
1 865700 865700 C T exonic SAMD11
1 865705 865705 C T exonic SAMD11
1 871215 871215 C G exonic SAMD11
1 871229 871229 G C exonic SAMD11
```

I have attempted something like this, but I can never get it quite to work:

Sorry in advance if someone covered this, I looked quite a bit and didn't find this problem. I have only been using awk for about two weeks and just started programming in February. Thanks a lot for input!

Comment: All that's wrong with your code is a missing space between `awk` and `'` and a spurious close-bracket (`}`) after your `for` condition. Your shell should have told you about the first issue and awk about that second syntax error and pointed you right to that character when you tried to run it. If those didn't happen you need to get a new shell and/or a new awk. If those DID happen, what is it abut the error messages you didn't understand?

Comment: Hi Ed-- that missing space was just my bad, red-eyed, up all night copy and paste job actually ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this should do:

```
awk 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/Alt/) f=i;next} {print $f}' file
A
A
A
T
T
T
G
C
```

It will search for the location of `Alt` in row  `1`, then store this position in `f`
When found it will print the data from the column stored in `f`

Comment: +1 for figuring out what was wanted. I didn't make it past reading his script since I there wasn't any expected output, nor a statement of in what way it "doesn't work" and the script had a couple of syntax errors so I assumed THAT was his problem. I suspect he really wants `$i=="Alt"` but it probably doesn't make any difference with his data.

Comment: Thanks to you both, and sorry for the bad form on my answer, I will be more careful next time! This solution works, Jotne. Can you tell me what exactly the first line NR==1 is doing?

Comment: `NR==1` do this action for the first line only.  `NR` is the line number.

Comment: How could I make this work on other line than the 1st (of unknown number actually, but containing known pattern)? I have a VCF file of genetic variants where my "header" line always starts with `#CHROM`. It then contains names of fields including sample names - I then want to extract column for particular sample, but this #CHROM line is preceded with long header with variable number of lines (all beginning with ##) so `NR==1` doesn't work for me.

Comment: PS: the header line I want to use is also the only line in the file containing sample names, so I could also match the sample name directly, however my attempts still fail :/

Comment: ok I figured it out, I had a problem elsewhere in the command, which was masking what was going on.. simple pattern matching `/#CHROM/` in place of `NR==1` can be used